# Opening a TCP socket from an Azure Website to an external server

Tags: c#, sockets, azure, tcp, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to open a TCP socket programmatically in C# from an `Azure Website` to an external server?

I have a need to check if another server is online - as ping cannot be used on Azure I was going to use TCP socket that the external server is configured to accept.

The code I have used locally works perfectly when pinging a public web server, however on Azure it doesn't work.

I'm aware that you can't ping due to the load balancer on Azure - but are opening TCP sockets out of the question too?

Can this be achieved? If not - how else can I check if an external server is alive without using a lengthy work around?

Note: There is definitely no firewall / port / IP issue with the external server.

**This is my code that works on my local dev machine and on Rackspace**

```
 public static bool TcpConnectivityTest(string ipAddress, int port = 1433, int timeoutMillisec = 2000)
    {
        Socket socket = null;

        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, false);

            var result = socket.BeginConnect(ipAddress, port, null, null);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeoutMillisec, true);

            return socket.Connected;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null != socket)
            {
                socket.Close();
                socket.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Outbound connections like what you have there should work fine in Azure Websites. I have tried your code with Google's ip address over port 80 and 443 and a sql azure server over 1433 and both connects fine.

Azure Websites will only restrict listening to ports other than 80 and 443 for inbound traffic, but not connecting to remote ports. You can also listen on local loopback ports.

Comment: So is it not possible to listen on azure websites from ports other than 80 or 443?