# Communicate with legacy TCP IP application via port from azure website

Tags: azure-web-app-service, tcp

I have an azure website and I need when a user performs an action that it connects in the background to a legacy TCP IP application which communicates over port 9031: This will need to both send and receive data.

If I deployed this website on a physical server or virtual machine, I could obviously open port 9031 on the firewall.

I'm unsure of how to open these ports when deploying as an azure website, can this be done?

Comment: By 'This will need to both send and receive data.' do you mean that tcp connections will be initialized both ways?

Comment: Simon we will be sending data out to a TCP/IP server and expecting a response back.

Comment: Outbound should "just work". Also have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21925629/468244) and comment that seem to describe the same situation

Answer (score 0):

Theres no option to configure any firewall rules on Web Apps (Azure Websites). If you need more control, you need to use cloud services (web/worker roles).

Cloud service configuration is done in the ServiceDefinition.csdef

```
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
  <InputEndpoint name="myendpoint" protocol="tcp" port="9031" localPort="9031" />
</Endpoints>
```

If you decide to leverage cloud services, it might be neccessary to create a startup task to configure the firewall on the instance/server.

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="my rule" dir=in localport=9031 protocol=TCP action=allow

Also, you could leverage startups tasks to install 'legacy stuff' if you use cloud services. Thats not possible on Web apps.

Let me know if it helps.